# Python textblob installation on VS code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pip, textblob

[Image screenshot of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/omkpA.png)

I am unable to install the textblob package in VScode. Not sure why it keeps me giving the following error, I am not connected through a VPN. Any troubleshooting help is appreciated.

Install the Textblob package in VScode and scrape content for SEO analysis

Comment: Can you paste the error on you question and not a picture of it use ```sh <paste here> ```